# AppCode PSI Plugin Development - Find reference protocol property

Tags: swift, intellij-plugin, appcode

Having a protocol

```
protocol MyTest {
   var isCorrect: Bool { get }
}
```

And a class that implements the protocol

```
class Super: MyTest {
  var isCorrect: Bool = false
}
```

How can you find the declaration of the `isCorrect` property when in PSI mode?
I do have a reference to `SwiftVariableDeclaration` when I'm analyzing the `Super` class, but I would like to get a reference to the actual declaration of the `isCorrect` inside the `MyTest` protocol.

I've tried `SwiftVariableDeclaration.swiftSymbol` but I'm not sure how to get a reference to the declaration.

Appreciate any hints into how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the declaration of the property.
What you're looking for is the declaration of its ancestors.

```
SwiftHierarchySearch.getAllSuperProperties(variable)
```

(Note that a variable declaration can contain multiple variables, so you'll need to pick one.)